# ip-up does not trigger when using built-in cisco vpn on mac osx lion

Tags: mac, vpn, routing, osx-lion, cisco-vpn-client

I am using Cisco VPN client over lion and I want to make the ip-up and ip-down work. There is no sign of any action taken when I connect or disconnect this VPN connection. I really doubt whether the syntax has been changed or even this kind if connection is triggering the ip-up. Logically, it must be set over ppp but when using the following codes and instructions on them, there is no sign of any output in the log file:

- http://www.macfreek.nl/mindmaster/Modify_PPTP_Routing_Table
- http://www.aidanfindlater.com/use-vpn-for-specific-sites-on-mac-os-x

Going for error, which there is no sign of it, using the following page:

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060616150640529

I couldn't find the `/var/log/ppp/vpnd.log` log file.

Also the files are given full permission 0755 or a+x or even 777 using the following command:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/ppp/ip-up
```

Any clue on how to debug this would be appreciated. I am totally confused, `netstat -rn -f inet` doesn't show the routes. Even when the routes are added manually, closing the VPN connection does not run the ip-down and the routes must be deleted manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to security.

Remove the file then create an empty one using the following command:

```
 sudo touch /etc/ppp/ip-up
```

Then:

```
 sudo vi /etc/ppp/ip-up
```

And finally:

```
 sudo chmod a+x /etc/ppp/ip-up
```

I think the point is to use sudo whenever you create/edit that file.

Comment: I will check it out but probabely it must be correct.

Comment: This works with a PPTP VPN, but not the built in Cisco IPsec VPN, which the OP was asking for.